# Youtube Data Api has commentCount field and is this the number of comments on channel?

Tags: youtube-api

I'm using Youtube Data Api v3 and there is a field called commentsCount in statistics section, I wanted to know if this is the comments for made by different users on a channel or is the comments made by the channel user on several videos.

for example if I send a HTTP request for Channel 4 on Demand which has lots of comments made by users, I only get

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername=4oD&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

HTTP Response

```
{
"kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
"etag": "\"jSwUP5mXUGwzAFbnLazODtWp_hU/wSdSPc8UxAJku7v41o3DVmEytAU\"",
"pageInfo": {
"totalResults": 1,
"resultsPerPage": 5
},
"items": [
{
"kind": "youtube#channel",
"etag": "\"jSwUP5mXUGwzAFbnLazODtWp_hU/qDF5UBIAV1LXx_oOE_V-wpUvx7c\"",
"id": "UCQQGTtqKZf0S0pQ2ey5c4Ag",
"statistics": {
"viewCount": "9245",
"commentCount": "2",
"subscriberCount": "62314",
"hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
"videoCount": "1"
}
}
]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Youtube API v3 says that "commentCount is the number of comment for the channel". This means that commentCount is not the total number of comment for all of channel's videos but for comment for channel. As we know, we can comment for a specific channel in the discussion part of the channel like [here](https://www.youtube.com/user/ZeroEmpires/discussion)

Comment: Hi, I've tried to look for this information on youtube api documentation, no luck. Can you send me the link where it says commentCount is actually the comment for specific channel rather than the SUM of comments for all videos uploaded by that channel. Thanks

Comment: [HERE](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels) See this link and look at "statistics.commentCount" property in the Properties. I have tried it for my channel and it is really for channel.