# Is "commentCount" in a YouTube channel's statistics not about comments posted by users in channel's discussion section on YouTube?

Tags: youtube-api

I'm using YouTube API v3 to develop an analytics suite right now and just found that YouTube API is showing some interesting numbers in the ***"commentCount"*** section for some channels. Here is a snapshot for data I retrieved for a particular channel

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"9Y5jTkxN1JET3y-M4wKMA5aK7Mk/wDjBbzayu_vYIuwxeT5PN0Eeq_A\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"9Y5jTkxN1JET3y-M4wKMA5aK7Mk/9HSFmJPrmkP1pe3ObV-qRzDSoOg\"",
   "id": "UC--Kcmmnxwny2dvYCa2VL_w",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "377449",
    "commentCount": "0",
    "subscriberCount": "3145",
    "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
    "videoCount": "85"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Now this channel has 1 comment in its YouTube's discussion section that has been posted by a user 1 year ago but the API states that there are 0 comments for this channel on YouTube. Can anyone help me on this one?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18593846/2274530

Comment: possible duplicate of [Youtube Data Api has commentCount field and is this the number of comments on channel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593188/youtube-data-api-has-commentcount-field-and-is-this-the-number-of-comments-on-ch)