# YouTube Data Api v3 consistently returns invalid statistics

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm using YouTube Data v3 in order to get statistics of a certain channel. To be precise I'm following [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#http-request) documentation.

I can get all data properly except for **commentCount** property. For example GET request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&forUsername=Kurzgesagt&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Which results in **commentCount** = **23**

This is obviously not correct as this channel has much more than that.

Same thing happens to **almost** all other channels (not all of them). Is there any particular reason for this behaviour? Why does it return this number?

I've been monitoring this value for more than a week and it hasn't changed once in that time period.

Edit: I know that **commentCount** property should return number of comments on that channel (not sum of all videos), but for some reason this doesn't really match. You can compare the commentCount I mentioned with real comments for Kurzgesagt channel on YT directly.

Answer (score 0):

CommentCount returns the number of comments in the channel, not the sum of all comments in the channel's videos, this has already been answered here [Youtube Data Api has commentCount field and is this the number of comments on channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593188/youtube-data-api-has-commentcount-field-and-is-this-the-number-of-comments-on-ch)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, I know. But for example the channel I mentioned has a lot more comments than that. Check that out: https://www.youtube.com/user/Kurzgesagt/discussion

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be more than one channels for that user, so is the link that you provided actually supposed to bring back the expected feedback ? There is no specified channel id on your URL.

Try the following:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet%2Creplies&allThreadsRelatedToChannelId=ChannelId&key={YOUR_API_KEY}