# Imprecise number of comments and replies in Youtube Data Api

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get a number of comments and replies for a video from Youtube Data Api v3. It looks like sometimes the `statistics.commentCount` property of [video resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource) and the `snippet.totalReplyCount` property of [comment thread resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads#resource) contain imprecise numbers. It's interesting that for example `statistics.viewCount` property, which contains much higher numbers, seems to be precise. Is there any caching involved or something like this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593188/youtube-data-api-has-commentcount-field-and-is-this-the-number-of-comments-on-ch/18593846#18593846).

> Youtube API v3 says that "commentCount is the number of comment for
>   the channel". This means that commentCount is not the total number of
>   comment for all of channel's videos but for comment for channel. As we
>   know, we can comment for a specific channel in the discussion part of
>   the channel like [here](https://www.youtube.com/user/ZeroEmpires/discussion).

You can also check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels) for the further details about Channels.

Comment: Thank you for response, but I'm checking number of comments of video resource and reply count of comment thread resource, not channel resource.

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled upon a similar case. I was able to come to a conclusion that - `statistics.commentCount` returned on the videoResource gives the total count of comments + replies to that comment together.

I've tried a couple of videos and found this to be the case. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to improve code formatting. See [answer].